# Trying to install Python audiolab module, module not found

Tags: python, module, numpy, installation

Not well experienced with doing installs. I finally got scikits.audiolab-0.11.0 installed, I think. Now the module cannot be found.

```
from audiolab import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named audiolab
```

**Does this need that I need to add it to my PATH or something? And how should I do that?**

Below are 1. the last few lines of messages I got from the scikits.audiolab-0.11.0 install, and then below that 2. the results from echo $PATH on my machine.

```
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for scikits.audiolab==0.11.0
Searching for numpy==1.6.1
Best match: numpy 1.6.1
Adding numpy 1.6.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for scikits.audiolab==0.11.0
```

echo $PATH

```
Macintosh:~ wolf$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that wherever the `audiolab` package is stored, that that filepath is on your **`PYTHONPATH`**.

`PATH` is used to launch programs, `PYTHONPATH` is where Python looks for modules.

Comment: In my .bash_profile? Like This: PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH or like this: PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
export PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: The directory, not the file